# How many ways can you choose 1 from each of 10 groups of 33?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am doing a data science project on predicting sports data, and ran into a combination/permutation problem that I can't recall how to solve from my probability courses.

I need to choose one athlete from each of 10 weight classes, where each weight class contains 33 athletes. I assume the number of possible combinations of this is too large to iterate through, but am wondering what is this number? To clarify, the final "choice" is one athlete from each weight class (125, 133, 141, etc.) making up what would result in something like a fantasy team. The question being, how many possible "teams" could be made?

I know if we consider only 1 weight class, there is obviously 33 ways when choosing only 1 athlete, (n=33, r=1) but am wondering how to extrapolate this to 10 groups of 33.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all the groups are disjoints (an athlete couldn't be in two weight categories), you have $33$ ways of choosing someone in the first group, then $33$ ways of choosing someone in the second group, and so on.

In the end, there are 
$$\underbrace{33\times33\times\dots\times33}_{10\text{ times}}=33^{10}\text{ ways}$$